Finite Difference For a Fourth Order PDE With Neumann Boundary Conditions.
I'm trying to implement a method I found for image decomposition that boils down to solving a PDE of fourth order. The equation in question is
$$
u_t = -\frac{1}{2\lambda}\Delta\left(\text{div}\left(\frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|}\right)\right) - (u-f)\quad \text{ in } (0,\infty) \times \text{Int}(\Omega)\\
$$
with boundary conditions
$$u(0,x,y) = f(x,y) \text{ in } \Omega,\; \left.\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}\right|_{\partial \Omega} = 0.\; \left.\dfrac{\partial \text{div}\left(\frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|}\right)}{\partial n}\right|_{\partial \Omega} = 0 $$
where $\Omega$ is an axis-aligned rectangle (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) and $f\colon \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ is a known function.
My goal is to use finite difference and write $u^n_{i,j}=u(n\Delta t, ih,jh)$ for $h>0$ (in this case $h=1$, since it's an image and we have pixels as the smallest difference). The LHS of the equation seems easy enough but I have no idea how to tackle the first, fourth-order term, of the RHS. When it comes to the boundary conditions, the first one is easy enough, how do I implement the second two in the discretization?
The Paper I'm trying to implement is
Stanley Osher, Andrés Solé, and Luminita Vese. "Image Decomposition and Restoration Using Total Variation Minimization and the $H^{-1}$ norm." Multiscale Modeling & Simulation 1, no. 3 (2003): 349-370. doi:10.1137/S1540345902416247. Retrieved from https://doi.org/10.1137/S1540345902416247
